# Why sendFile is ignoring parameters provided for it?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the following simple server.js to randomly point to two different HTML files on the server. However, it is automatically redirecting to index.html (not even in the parameters any more) and not the index1.html or index2.html.

I am not sure what I am missing here

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if((Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1)>1)
  {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index1.html");
  }

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index2.html");
});

/*--------------------Routing Over----------------------------*/

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Comment: I'm just speculating here, but do you actually have an index.html file in your docroot? If so, the static middleware you're using (`app.use(express.static('public'))`) might be serving up the static file before your route is even getting hit.

Comment: I do, does that mean if I use (app.use(express.static('public'))) then the res.SendFile is pretty useless and it defaults to the index.html?

Comment: Maybe not. IIRC, Express will handle its requests based on the order you defined handlers in. So if you move the `app.use(express.static...` line below your route definitions, it might use the route before the static middleware.

Comment: I just running your code. If i understood correct, it seems to be working as your thought. Server sending  randomly one of index1.html and index2.html.

Comment: yes @Enxtur it is a simple A/B routing that I was trying to implement in JS.

Answer (score 0):

As i executed your code it was looking fine to me and changing file index1.html and index2.html randomly.

If you want to change with route as well then i'll suggest below scenerio :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3002;

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/index1.html', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index1.html");
});

app.get('/index2.html', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index2.html");
});



app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if((Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1)>1)
  {
    console.log("index1");
 res.redirect("/index1.html");
  }
  console.log("index2");
 res.redirect("/index2.html");

});
app.listen(3002);
```

Comment: oh nice, you are using res.redirect to redirect to a get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To send either index1.html or index2.html you have to use the else condition. Further, I have used the path module to create the path, which is the best practice.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1) > 1) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/index1.html"));
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/index2.html"));
    }
});

/*--------------------Routing Over----------------------------*/
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Comment: I don't think it was the else. When running the code it was redirecting me to index.html. Whereas there is no index.html in the code.